# How to use INSERT OR REPLACE correctly?

Tags: android, sqlite

I was originally looking for an `INSERT OR UPDATE` ability in SQLite but searches showed similar question askers being pointed to using `INSERT OR REPLACE`.

I'm obviously misunderstanding how this works and obviously I can't use `WHERE` as I'm getting the following SQLiteException...

```
08-12 01:38:22.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 01:38:22.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29242): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
                        near "WHERE":
                            syntax error: 
                                INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SERVERS (
                                    server_name,
                                    service_uri_mobile,
                                    service_uri_wifi,
                                    valid_ssids,
                                    username,password
                                ) VALUES (
                                    'Default',
                                    'http://myserver.com:8790/',
                                    'http://192.168.1.1:8790/',
                                    '[]',
                                    'admin',
                                    'password')
                                WHERE server_name='Default'
```

The SQL string I'm using is as follows...

```
String UpdateString = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SERVERS " +
    "(server_name,service_uri_mobile,service_uri_wifi,valid_ssids,username,password) VALUES ('" +
    locater.getServerName() + "','" +
    locater.getServiceUriMobile().toString() + "','" +
    locater.getServiceUriWifi().toString() + "','" +
    locater.getValidSsids().toString() + "','" +
    locater.getUsername() + "','" +
    locater.getPassword() + "') " +
    "WHERE server_name='" + locater.getServerName() + "'";
```

I've looked at [this page](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) explaining `REPLACE` but don't quite understand it. How would I re-write the above SQLite command and have it only try to replace the record where the `server_name` matches (i.e., the equivalent of a `WHERE` clause)?

Comment: Is that your exact SQL query? I swear I didn't delete the trailing `)` on it if it is...

Comment: @Jared - yes it WAS my exact SQL and I realise what you mean - I've edited to add the closing bracket after `locater.getPassword()` but I'm getting the same error. Thanks for formatting the exception BTW.

Comment: You get the same exact error?

Comment: @Jared: Yes but notice I've added the closing bracket to the error in my question. So..exact but now with a closing bracket after `'password'`

Comment: I saw that. If `REPLACE` were the error, I would expect the error to occur there and not on the syntax error at the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Are you operating on any columns that are unique?

Comment: Aaah - no not on any unique columns, I think I'm beginning to see now - the `REPLACE` is triggered if the `INSERT` attempt causes a conflict with a unique column???

Comment: I think so, at least looking at the docs you linked to. Replace appears to be concerned with columns that are `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Success!!! I made the `server_name` column `UNIQUE` (thought I'd already done it as it needs to be) and I got rid of the `WHERE` clause and it's working now. Please feel free to pad your comments out to an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation (and mirroring the comments below the question), `REPLACE` should be used when `UPDATE`ing (or in other words changing) columns that are `UNIQUE`. To wit:

> REPLACE
>
> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm
>   deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation
>   prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command
>   continues executing normally.

http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Comment: Thank you for your help - I don't do very much with SQL and it was simply a case of not understanding what the docs were trying to tell me. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the points; I'm not a SQL all-star, but sometimes I can figure out what's going on. It is a different animal at times.